# jQuery.post() and redirect via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, jquery

I am using `jQuery.post()` to send data to the server, when the server sends data back to the client, the post() callback is invoked. I know that the server might response with the redirect header field ("`Location`").

currently, the redirect does not occur. what can be the reason?
is there any possibility to run a script before the redirect occur?

UPDATE:
enclosed a snipped code. i know that the POST method is accepted by the server, and that the server responds to the POST. somehow, always the `error()` is being invoked (it seems like it happends even before the response is accepted by the client\browswer).

what is wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#loginForm").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            data : $("#loginForm :input").not("#loginBtn").serialize(),
            url : "http://localhost/auth",
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("success");
                alert(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Location"));
            }, 
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add error detail in your question too?

Answer (score 2):

`jquery.post()` works by issuing an Ajax request. In an Ajax call, the PHP script works asynchronously (think of it as a background thread). Thus, the PHP script cannot redirect the client's browser. The way to go would be to have the PHP script responsd with the URL to redirect to, and redirect using javascript.

In your POST callback:

```
function(data){  //data will be the URL to redirect to, sent back by the PHP script
window.location = data;
}
```

**EDIT**

From Jquery documentation on [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**statusCode(added 1.5)Map**

```
Default: {}
```

A map of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.

Comment: i am looking for generic solution, something that does not depend on the server implementaion. i.e., using the HTTP headers, etc.

Comment: you could try checking for a 302 header status when you receive the response. I'm not sure how you could get the location though, without the PHP script explicitly sending it to you

Comment: please forget about PHP. is there any possibility to access the HTTP response headers in jQuery/javascript/DOM?

Comment: @MrIzik: see edit on how to handle HTTP response statuses in jquery. `jquery.post()` is a shorthand for `jquery.ajax()`. You'll have to handle a status code of `302`

Comment: When the server side script redirects, it sets he Header status to 302 (temporary redirect). The success function only gets called when the header status is 200 (success). If you do not map specific status codes like in my code snippet above, all header statuses other than 200 will cause the error function to get called

Comment: firstly thanks a lot, secondly, regardless of the statusCode, i wish to invoke `success()` and `error()`, when data is received back from the server, or an error occurred respectively.

Comment: moreover, i use chrome to test the web application i program, i see that the `error()` callback is invoked even before a reponse from the server has been accepted by the client\browser. i even tried to increase the ajax timeout, but it does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please in redirect case get simple response without redirecting print any flag like "redirect" and and write client side redirect using

```
if(responce == 'redirect')
    window.location = "Your url"
```

Do not redirect on server.

It will work.

Answer (score -2):

If you perform an operation that results in a redirect, JQuery does not detect it. The browser handles it automatically behind the scenes, to create a seamless experience.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. the browser does not perform the redirect. i think it is because the server response is being handled by the `jQeury.post()` callback function.

Comment: For example, if you post but your session has timed out, the server might redirect you to a login page. Your jquery call has absolutely no idea that this has occured, because the browser processes it for you. In this situation, you have no control over the response. If you do have control in your case, then you should include something to let JQuery know. Sorry, I don't really understand your problem enough, so I apologise if my reply isn't useful =)